# How Can I Access BIOS From External Monitor?

Tags: display, bios, netbook

A few months ago, the screen on my Samsung N150 Plus Netbook broke. I removed the broken screen, and began working on the external monitor instead. This worked fine, except from the fact that I couldn't access the BIOS using my external monitor.

Is there any way I can access the BIOS using my external monitor (VGA)?

P.S. I have Linux Mint installed on this netbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not easy task, either you will find appropriate BIOS that support mirroring to external monitor on boot up stage and re-flash existing (assume you borrowed someones screen to do that) or you can dump BIOS and patch it to reroute output. Other way is to find LVDS to HDMI/VGA converter and hook it to your motherboard(make sure you found right LVDS connectors for your laptop) or if you have a patience, bunch of time and electronic skills then you can make your own converter from your LVDS (protocol itself is actually very simple and if you find some panel from other computers that shouldn't be exact as your model then it relatively easier task to make adapter from LVDS connector on motherboard to some alien screen panel)